# Do I lose reputation when I downvote things?

Tags: support, specific-question, reputation

I just downvoted a question I found a bit ridiculous, and when I clicked on my profile and looked at my reputation tab, it said "-1 reputation".  I don't know what my reputation was beforehand, but do I lose reputation when I downvote?  If so, is there a reason why?

Comment: Not only Writing SE but all other SE websites follow the same pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not lose reputation for downvoting a question. You do lose reputation for downvoting an answer. You can find more [here](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

> You lose reputation when:
>
> - your question is voted down: −2
> - your answer is voted down: −2
> - you vote down an answer: −1
> - you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
> - one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100

[This Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-downvoting) also has more information.